# dynamically set checked checkbox in gridview in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having id or values in hidden field. I wanted to set checked=true to checkbox which is in gridview ItemTemplate using javascript only(no jQuery please)

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("ID").checked = true/false
```

Comment: I am getting same id for all checkboxes in gridview

Answer (score 0):

all your id's should be unique. however, you can implement it yourself, by traversing all "checkboxes" in page, and checking their "id" attribute. see [getElementsByClass](http://www.anyexample.com/webdev/javascript/javascript_getelementsbyclass_function.xml)  which uses same principal.